# Essential singularity of c.c.(z)

Tags: complex-analysis, problem-solving

According to my lecture notes, $z^*$ has an essential singularity (asterix denotes complex conjugate). However, it is not explained why nor at which point. Can anyone elaborate where the singularity is?

The reason why I ask is because 
$$
\oint(z^* dz) \neq 0 
$$

where the curve is a circle centered at the origin, which must mean that indeed there is a singularity.

Comment: The definition of an essential singularity that i know about requires the function to be meromorphic in a neighboorhood of the singularity. $z^\ast$ however isn't meromorphic anywhere in $\mathbb C$. So which definition do you use?

Comment: That doesn't really make sense, conjugation is nowhere complex differentiable, and to have an essential singularity, in the usual understandings, the function needs to be holomorphic on an open set containing the point in its boundary.

Comment: @LeBtz I updated my question, Since Cauchy's Integral Theorem doesn't give that the integral over the closed curve is zero, then there must be a singularity, right?

Comment: @BillyJean No, to speak of singularities, we need a function that is holomorphic on some non-empty open set. $z\mapsto z^\ast$ is nowhere complex differentiable. Cauchy's integral theorem says nothing about such functions.